# How to use malloc properly in C?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, allocation

I'm writing a program in which I want to find all abundant numbers until 28124. I can do it with a static array but I want to improve my code and adjust it with a dynamic way.
Here is my code:

```
    
    #define N 28124
 
    bool is_abundant(int number)
    {
        int i;
        int sum=0;
        for(i=1;i<=number/2;i++)
        {
            if(number % i == 0)
                sum += i;
            if(sum > number)    return true;
        }
    
        return false;
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        clock_t start = clock();
    
        int i, j=0;
        int *abundants = NULL;  
    
        for(i=12;i<N;i++)
        {
            if(is_abundant(i))
            {
                abundants = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
                assert(abundants);
                abundants[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", abundants[i]);
        }

        clock_t end = clock();   
        double time = (double) (end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("Execution time: %lf\n", time);
        return 0;
    }
```

The program aborts due to assert failure but how can I change it so as to works properly in a dynamic way?

Comment: I recommend finding a tutorial for dynamic allocation that explains the basics.

Comment: You are allocating 1 single item each lap in the loop, then overwrite it and create a memory leak next lap. Instead of doing malloc inside the loop, simply malloc 12 integers once, before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to multiply `sizeof(int)` by the number of ints you want to allocate. Otherwise you just allocate a single element.

You also need to use `realloc()` so you grow the existing array rather than allocating a new array.

```
    for(i=12;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(is_abundant(i))
        {
            abundants = realloc(abundants, (j+1) * sizeof(int));
            assert(abundants);
            abundants[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `sizeof(int)` -> `sizeof(*abundants)` maybe?

Comment: Notably, code like this is just artificial academic stuff. In a real world application, you would never call realloc repeatedly in a loop like this, because doing so is very inefficient. In the rare scenario where there's some strange requirement that you _must_ use dynamic allocation, come hell or high water, then you'd either `malloc(12*sizeof(int))` (and then realloc to the actual size afterwards, if you must), or use a linked list etc.